# Open application after tray icon click or double-click instead of menu

Tags: gnome, icons, menu, telegram

**SETUP**:
I have telegram icon after installing it with `sudo apt install telegram-desktop`. Telegram version 3.6.1. OS - Ubuntu 22.04. And instead of default applications dash panel I'm using dash-to-panel ([dash-to-panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)) but I think it does not matter, since the problem is the same for default menu as well.

**PROBLEM**:
When I was using Ubuntu 18.04 telegram would open chats after double-click on its icon in tray. However now on Ubuntu 22.04 after double-click nothing happens, after single click a menu [Open telegram, Disable notifications, Quit Telegram] is shown. Since I frequently use Telegram to reopen chats, is there any way to restore the old behavour - open telegram chats after click or double-click?

Telegram developers say it's a tray settings issue which I don't know how to change in Ubuntu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have installed years ago Telegram by downloading the `tsetup.2.5.1.tar.xz` file from their site. Telegram is updating itself automatically and now it is on version 4.6. This problem does not occur here (Ubuntu 22.10 and using **Dash to Panel** like you). The menu you have on your screenshot is displayed when I right click. And when I left click normally the Telegram main window is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Removed Ubuntu Software installation, unzipped & launched tsetup.4.6.0.tar.xz from https://desktop.telegram.org/ - the problem remains...

Comment: Normally, I close the Telegram window when not in use, so that it is "minimized to tray". After that, when I single left click (normal mouse click) the tray icon it will display the menu, but when I double left click (normal mouse double click) it will display the Telegram window. However, single or double ___right___ clicking will display just the menu (as you have described). So, check (1) that you have closed the Telegram window and (2) that you are ___left double clicking___ on the tray icon.